# Is there any way to extract all xsd from given wsdl file?

Tags: web-services, spring-integration

I am working in a spring integration webs service module,where I need to extract all xsd from wsdl. Is there any tool or a way where I can extract all xsd from given wsdl file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clrear why just WSDL isn't enough for you.

Try to use SoapUI tool to get deal with that WSDL.

I can guess that you want to generate client model based on the server WSDL.

So, maybe this one can help, too: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard ?

Or this http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html, if you use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Hi Artem,Thanks for your reply. Actually I want schema from wsdl provided by vendor to generate Java Objects,so that I can process request in my service layer. Anyhow I received only wsdl file and this wsdl contains multiple schema references. I actually want to extract the schemas from this wsdl so that using jaxb xjc compiler , I can generate the Java objects. I can actually get all the xsd manually by clicking the xsd links provided within the wsdl but I am looking some tool which can import xsd's used within the wsdl for saving my time in future for any such case. Please suggest.

Comment: How about to write your own? Since you can parse WSDL XML and get the desired info. However I can guess that it won't work for all WSDLs, because the might have different structure and don't provide links for XSD, but squesh they as inline.